# Why do random effects in a mixed model always have a mean of zero?

Tags: mixed-model

I am studying the linear mixed model $y=X\beta + Z\gamma + \epsilon$ where $\beta$ is a vector of fixed effects, and it seems that $\gamma$ is usually specified as $\gamma \sim N(0,I\sigma^2)$.

My question is why does $\gamma$ have a mean of zero?

If I specify $\gamma \sim N(\alpha,I\sigma^2)$, where $\alpha$ is a vector of non-zero constants, then $y=X\beta + Z\alpha + Z\gamma^* + \epsilon$ where $\gamma^* \sim N(0,I\sigma^2)$. Is there anything incoherent with this model, can $Z$ wield both fixed and random effects?

Comment: In general the columns of the $Z$ matrix correspond to some or all of the columns of the $X$ matrix, consequently the non-zero means of the random effects can be found in as fixed effects in $\beta$

Answer (score 4):

The mean of $\gamma$ is already played by the intercept. If you include both an intercept and the parameter $\alpha$ ($\gamma \sim N(\alpha, \sigma^2 I)$), then the model will be overparametrised and there will be confounding. The model is said to be non-identifiable.

i.e.

$$y = \alpha + \gamma,\quad \gamma \sim \mathcal N(\color{green}{0}, \sigma^2_\gamma)$$ 
is the same as $$y = \gamma,\quad \gamma \sim \mathcal N(\color{green}{\alpha}, \sigma^2_\gamma)$$

---

*EDIT*: As noted by @fcop in his comment below, the above discussion concerns a random intercept. In the same way, the mean of a random effect is played by the corresponding fixed effect coefficient.

Comment: You can have random effects on slopes also I think ?

Comment: Similary, the mean of the random effect of the slope is played by the fixed effect of the slope.

Comment: This is what I said in my comment below the question

Comment: Indeed. I ve just tried to make it more explicit ;-)

Comment: So based on the above discussion, if I don't include the fixed effect term $Z\alpha$ explicitly in the model, then I can have $\gamma \sim  N(\alpha,I\sigma^2)$ without the identification issue?

Comment: Yes: if you don't include the intercept in the "fixed effect part", you can include it as the mean of the random effect. Same with other parameters.